# CSS GRID how would I put some space between header and grid container with height:100%?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have looked everywhere on stack overflow and none of the questions answer this directly so I would like to know if any of you have a solution for this or maybe I'm just doing something absolutely wrong?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  height: 100%vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "side1 middle side2" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 80% 20%;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
}

.side1 {
  grid-area: side1;
}

.middle {
  grid-area: middle;
  overflow: auto;
}

.side2 {
  grid-area: side2;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="side1">side 1</div>
  <div class="middle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure architecto dolore libero dignissimos perspiciatis aliquam cumque corporis? Aperiam in tempore fugiat eveniet! Quaerat fuga molestias tenetur voluptatum, eligendi, est laboriosam quis illo
    hic nobis eos aspernatur non! Tempore minus dolorem placeat, architecto ea magnam pariatur officia nobis, dicta quas exercitationem ducimus laudantium illum minima, alias quod consequatur nihil laborum?</div>
  <div class="side2">side2</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Adding `margin-bottom` to `.header` seems to not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in `height: 100%vh` it should be `height: 100vh`.
also margins will not work in the way you want if you set the header as `fixed`، so you have 2 options:

1. remove position: fixed
2. set margin/padding top to the container itself

you can check here https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-haze-un2xd?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed;` and add `display:block;` in .header class. Then add `margin-bottom: YOURSIZE;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution will be to put a block placeholder to occupy the space for your header since it is `position: fixed`, your original header won't take up any space.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}
.placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "side1 middle side2" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 80% 20%;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
}

.side1 {
  grid-area: side1;
}

.middle {
  grid-area: middle;
  overflow: auto;
}

.side2 {
  grid-area: side2;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="placeholder"><!--This is a placeholder--></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="side1">side 1</div>
  <div class="middle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure architecto dolore libero dignissimos perspiciatis aliquam cumque corporis? Aperiam in tempore fugiat eveniet! Quaerat fuga molestias tenetur voluptatum, eligendi, est laboriosam quis illo
    hic nobis eos aspernatur non! Tempore minus dolorem placeat, architecto ea magnam pariatur officia nobis, dicta quas exercitationem ducimus laudantium illum minima, alias quod consequatur nihil laborum?</div>
  <div class="side2">side2</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```